# Getting information from Response on Network Tab

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I need to be able to grab information from the network tab on Chrome, specifically a response, using Python and Selenium.  I included a screenshot of this page with a box around the information I'm trying to grab.  Once I get it, I can figure out parsing the information I need.  I've been searching all day and I can't find anything on getting information from the network tab.

Thanks

Image updated to show only the tab I need to capture.

[image]

Comment: the response is JS code. If you want JS code to be pulled, you can use _requests_ package in python to pull using the link.

Comment: @xenon - using what link?

Comment: from the network tab, you have selected the link. That link will give you a response.

Comment: @xenon - I selected that to show the information I am trying to capture.  There is no link on the page I am automating